# Having issues changing this assembly into C

Tags: assembly, x86

```
...
.L5: 
 movl 8(%ebp), %eax #  A(param) is at ebp + 8
 movl 12(%ebp), %edx # B(param) is at ebp + 12 
 movl %edx, %ecx
 subl %eax, %ecx 
 movl %ecx, %eax 
 addl $1, %eax 
 movl %eax, %edx 
 shrl $31, %edx 
 leal (%edx,%eax), %eax 
 sarl %eax  
 addl %eax, 8(%ebp) 
 movl 8(%ebp), %eax 
 cmpl 12(%ebp), %eax 
 jge .L5
```

I'm having issues reverse engineering this x86 and what I'm thinking right now is that it's a do-while but the expression that I am getting doesn't seem right and without using variables it is very long. I think at the `shrl $31, %edx`, the register `edx` should equal `((B-A)+1)>>31`? Am I way off?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's correct.